# How do I prevent over-correcting in my autonomous driving solution?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on an autonomous driving solution for Euro Truck Simulator 2 with OpenCV in C++.

Here is where we detect the curve of the road:

```
    int bottom_center = 160;
    int sum_centerline = 0;
    int count_centerline = 0;
    int first_centerline = 0;
    int last_centerline = 0;
    double avr_center_to_left = 0;
    double avr_center_to_right = 0;

    //#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 240; i > 30; i--){
        double center_to_right = -1;
        double center_to_left = -1;

        for (int j = 0; j < 150; j++) {
            if (contours.at<uchar>(i, bottom_center + j) == 112 && center_to_right == -1) {
                center_to_right = j;
            }
            if (contours.at<uchar>(i, bottom_center - j) == 112 && center_to_left == -1) {
                center_to_left = j;
            }
        }
        if (center_to_left != -1 && center_to_right != -1){
            int centerline = (center_to_right - center_to_left + 2 * bottom_center) / 2;
            if (first_centerline == 0) {
                first_centerline = centerline;
            }
            cv::circle(outputImg, Point(centerline, i), 1, Scalar(30, 255, 30), 3);
            cv::circle(outputImg, Point(centerline + center_to_right+20, i), 1, Scalar(255, 30, 30) , 3);
            cv::circle(outputImg, Point(centerline - center_to_left+10, i), 1, Scalar(255, 30, 30) , 3);
            sum_centerline += centerline;
            avr_center_to_left = (avr_center_to_left * count_centerline + center_to_left) / count_centerline + 1;
            avr_center_to_right = (avr_center_to_right * count_centerline + center_to_right) / count_centerline + 1;
            last_centerline = centerline;
            count_centerline++;
        }
        else {}
    }
```

And here is my current solution for steering:

```
int diff = 0;
    if (count_centerline != 0) {
        diff = sum_centerline / count_centerline - bottom_center;
        int degree = atan2(last_centerline - first_centerline, count_centerline) * 180 / PI;
        //diff = (90 - degree);

        int move_mouse_pixel = diff;
        cout << "Steer: " << move_mouse_pixel << "px ";
        if (diff <= 20 || diff >= -20){
            SetCursorPos(pt.x + (move_mouse_pixel / 10), height / 2);
        }
        else{
            SetCursorPos(pt.x + (move_mouse_pixel / 25), height / 2);
        }
    }
```

Finally, here is a video of what my program currently does: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqyvoFuGKKk&feature=youtu.be

The current problem I have is that the steering does not center fast enough, leading it to continually over-correct until it swerves off the lane. I have tried to increase steering sensitivity in-game, to allow for faster or slower turning, but this either makes the truck spin out of control or not turn enough when driving along a large curve.

My current method just divides slight movements (between -20px and 20px) by 10, and large movements by 20. I've also tried reversing this but did not fix the over-correcting problem.

There are two possible solutions that I have found so far:

1. I could incrementally increase the divider for which we apply to move_mouse_pixel, therefore reducing the force of steering done between small movements.
2. Or, I could somehow make the program center the steering wheel more quickly. I am not sure how I would implement this.

What do you guys think?

Comment: I think that a [PID controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller) might be useful.

Comment: @BrianLittlefield Related: [Stanley: The Robot that Won the DARPA Grand Challenge](http://isl.ecst.csuchico.edu/DOCS/darpa2005/DARPA%202005%20Stanley.pdf). There is a section `9.2. Steering Control` that could be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that PID controller would be suitable for this task. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller
In your situation it would look similar to this:

```
            diffOld = diff;
            diff = sum_centerline / count_centerline - bottom_center;
            SetCursorPos(width/2 + Kp* diff + Kd*(diff - diffOld) , height / 2);
```

Do not use if statement in this controller. You need to keep steering  even if there is no error to corect. I would suggest to skip integral part, because your object integrate (when you do not drive straight you integrate error). You need to experimentally choose values of Kp and Kd parameters, for example with Ziegler–Nichols method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziegler%E2%80%93Nichols_method.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the information! I will look into this.